# Simplify assembly program

Tags: assembly, nested-loops, dos, masm, x86-16

I currently have this code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
.code
    CLRSCR:
        mov ax,0003h
        int 10h
    ROWCOLINIT:
        mov dh,0
        mov dl,0
    MYLOOP:
        mov ax,dx
        mov ah,0
        mov bl,2
        div bl
        cmp ah,0
        je EVENCOL
    ODDCOL:
        mov al,2
    CURSORINIT:
        mov ah,02h
        mov bh,0
        int 10h
    ATTRIBINIT:
        mov ah,09h
        mov bl,30h
    PRINTCHAR:
        mov cx,1
        int 10h
        inc dl
        cmp dl,5
        je RESETCOLINCROW2
    DONTRESETCOL:
        cmp dh,5
        je EXIT
        jmp MYLOOP
    LOOP2:
        mov ax,dx
        mov ah,0
        mov bl,2
        div bl
        cmp ah,0
        je EVENCOL2
    ODDCOL2:
        mov al,42
    CURSORINIT2:
        mov ah,02h
        mov bh,0
        int 10h
    ATTRIBINIT2:
        mov ah,09h
        mov bl,30h
    PRINTCHAR2:
        mov cx,1
        int 10h
        inc dl
        cmp dl,5
        je RESETCOLINCROW
    DONTRESETCOL2:
        cmp dh,5
        je EXIT
        jmp LOOP2   
    EXIT:
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
    RESETCOLINCROW:
        mov dl,0
        inc dh
        jmp DONTRESETCOL
    RESETCOLINCROW2:
        mov dl,0
        inc dh
        jmp DONTRESETCOL2
    EVENCOL:
        mov al,42
        jmp CURSORINIT
    EVENCOL2:
        mov al,2
        jmp CURSORINIT2

end
```

My program output is:

```
*☻*☻*
☻*☻*☻
*☻*☻*
☻*☻*☻
*☻*☻*
```

I'm trying to make this code simpler using 2 loops. How do I go about doing nested loops in assembler?

Comment: does the specs allow you to change to another language? :)

Comment: Maybe you should comment your code and tell us what this program should do at all?

Comment: Although you say you want to simplify to two loops, it is possible to generate the desired effect with one loop as well (single loop is simpler as well)

Comment: You don't need a loop at all. You can display that output with a single BIOS call.

Comment: LOL @RossRidge , that is true ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution, that uses 8086/8088 instructions only. It doesn't rely on 386 instructions so should run in any 8086/8088+ emulator.

The idea of this program is that we print 25 characters alternating between * and a smiley face (02h). We print 5 characters per line (advancing the cursor right after each character), and then skip to the beginning of the next line if we have printed 5 characters. We do this until we have printed out the number of required characters (25).

To alternate between * and smiley face I use the fact that the character I want is dependent on whether the current character I am processing (in *DI*) is odd or even. If it is even I print a * and if it is odd I print a smiley face.

I have provided comments in the code to give an idea of what is happening at each step. I use these registers as variables.

```
BP = Num of characters per row 
DI = Current character number we are processing  
BH = Current text page to print on 
BL = Attribute to use when printing to screen 
CX = Total number of characters to print with int 10h/ah=09h. Always = 1
DH = Current cursor row
DL = Current cursor column
```

The code I used is:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
outcharsarr db '*', 2    ; even = *  odd = smiley face

CHARSPERROW  equ 5       ; Number of characters to print per row
CHARSTOPRINT equ 25      ; Total number of characters to print

.code
    MAIN:
    mov ax, @data        ; Use the proper data segment
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax,0003h         ; Clear screen
    int 10h

    xor   dx, dx         ; Update cursor to 0,0 . DH=Row, DL=Column
    mov   ah, 2          
    int   10h

    mov   bp, CHARSPERROW; BP = Num of characters per row
    xor   di, di         ; DI = Current character number we are processing
    mov   bx, 0030h      ; BH = Current page to print on
                         ; BL = Attribute to use when printing
    mov   cx, 1          ; CX = Number of characters to print

printloop:
    xor   si, si         ; Index to even/odd array
    test  di, 1          ; Is current character pos even/odd?
    jz    pl_evenpos     ; if even si=0
    inc   si             ; if odd  si=1
pl_evenpos:    
    mov   al, outcharsarr[si] 
                         ;Print the character out based on even/odd index
    mov   ah, 09h
    int   10h

    dec   bp             ; dec number of chars still needed on current row
    ja    pl_nextcol     ; If we haven't printed enough for current row 
                         ; goto next column

    ; If we reach here we have printed the require number for this row
    ; advance to beginning of next row
    xor   dl, dl         ; col=0
    inc   dh             ; row=row+1
    mov   ah, 2          ; Update cursor
    int   10h
    mov   bp, CHARSPERROW 
                         ; Reset the number of characters needed on current row 
    jmp   pl_endloop

pl_nextcol:
    inc   dl             ; col=col+1
    mov   ah, 2          ; Update cursor
    int   10h

pl_endloop:
    inc   di
    cmp   di, CHARSTOPRINT
                         ; Have we reached total number of characters to print?
    jb    printloop      ;    If not got back and continue printing

    mov ah,4ch           ; Exit program
    int 21h

end MAIN
```